# Tahoe-LAFS over Tor

Tags: configuration, relays

_

Dear Tor-community,

We would like to run a tahoe-lafs-grid over tor, so different tahoe-lafs-nodes don't necessarily need to know each other. They should never reach each other outside of the tor network.

Is there any way to whitelist or specify tor-relay-nodes when connecting each tahoe-lafs-node, so huge traffic loads of the tahoe-lafs-grid don't have an impact on the whole tor network, but mainly only on the nodes hosted by us?

We wan't to provide a service accessible for everyone (including us), while also not slowing down the tor network.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You either route your traffic through tor relays or you don't get the anonymity that results from routing your traffic through tor network.
If you don't want each node to know the address of other nodes then you need to access them through hidden services